# Hibernate many to one mapping real time scenario

Tags: hibernate, transactions, many-to-one

Suppose we have a fruitseller who sells just 3 fruits and he has 3 customers.How will the hibernate mapping be done to track transactions? This was an interview question and I wasn't sure how transaction will be handled for many-to-one scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say:
One fruit can buy one and only one customer and each customer can buy one or more fruits.

In Customer entity you should have List annotated with @OneToMany and in Fruit entity you should have Customer annotated with @ManyToOne which indicates that each fruit can buy just one customer.

On the other hand, this easily can be @ManyToMany relation if you observe fruit object like this:
Table fruit:

```
| fruit_id | name  | count |
---------------------------
| 1        | apple | 100   |
| 2        | orange| 200   |
| 3        | peach | 300   |
```

and you can tell that each fruit can buy each customer and each customer can buy each fruit.
Join table with fruit_id and customer_id should look like:

```
| fruit_id | customer_id|
-------------------------
| 1        | 1          |
| 1        | 2          |
| 1        | 3          |
| 2        | 1          |
| 2        | 2          |
| 2        | 3          |
```